# issue with the dateFromString operator for MongoDB using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I have an issue with the `dateFromString` operator

I want to parse dates out of a string using the `dateFromString` operator. The dates are in the 'released' field in a certain collection

I am using Python 3.6.4, MongoDB shell version v3.6.2, pymongo '3.6.0'
I am received the following error message:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unrecognized expression '$dateFromString'

Can someone help on this please?

This is my code

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$limit' : 100
    },
    {
        '$project' : {
            'released': {
                '$cond': {
                    'if': {'$eq': ['$released', '']},
                    'then': '',
                    'else': {
                        '$dateFromString':{
                            'dateString': '$released'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        '$out': 'movies_scratch'
    }
]

pprint.pprint(list(client.database.collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

thx

Comment: What is your server version ? Run db.version() to confirm 3.6 server version

Comment: ah, i am on MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
I use the free tier version on Atlas, which is only available on 3.4
The dateFromString operator is only available on 3.6 and higher
I guess I need to upgrade then!
Thanks for your comment Veeram

Answer (score 5):

Check the mongoDB database version. If you are using the Atlas free tier it is still on 3.4.13 version. You will need a mongoDB 3.6 version for $dateFromString to work.

Comment: What if the version is below 3.6?